# Splash Screen API not support in Dark mode

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-12

I am trying to implement a splash screen.

I have followed the splash screen API approach implemented the
`implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha02'`

splash.xml

```
<style name="Theme.App.Start" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
  <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFF</item>
  <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_baby_changing_station_24</item>
  <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplashScreenApi</item>
</style>
```

splash.xml (for dark mode)

```
<style name="Theme.App.Start" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
   <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#3A3A3A</item>
   <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_baby_changing_station_24</item>
   <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplashScreenApi</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Start">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Start">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen()

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Still show the black icon in dark mode
[image: splash screen dark mode]

And perfectly work in light mode
[image: splash screen light mode]

> Device Name: Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro,
> Android Version: Android 10 (SDK 29)

Comment: Did you try with some other icons?

Comment: @SujalKumar Yeah, I tried that too.

Comment: Did you try with the beta01 ?

Comment: @VadimCaen I tried. But still not working. Sir can you share any Splash screen api project that works fine in other devices. Thanks.

Comment: The official sample works well:
https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/core/core-splashscreen/samples

Comment: @VadimCaen nope, it doesn't
https://imgur.com/a/9kF1Wr4

Comment: Does it work in the emulator?

Comment: I tried on a Redmi Note 7 and 9 with Android 9 and 10, in dark and light mode and they all work.

Comment: @VadimCaen Yes, It works perfectly in the emulator.

Comment: It's probably related to https://issuetracker.google.com/215214500

Comment: Have you found Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, I am getting splash as background color and launcher icon

I also face the same issue just follow my step

First of all, create values-v31(add same Theam and style file in this values-v31 folder) and values-night-v31 (add same Theam and style file in this values-night-v31 folder).

Don't use

```
   <style name="Theme.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/your_logo</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

use this one

```
 <style name="Theme.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.Common">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/your_logo</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: "Theme.SplashScreen.Common" - it's better

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplashScreenApi</item>
```

to this:

```
<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
```

(where **AppTheme** is your main theme name)

Also, there's no need to apply Splash theme in both activity and application. So I would suggest you to change this in **application** tag :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Start"
```

to this:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Actually `Theme.SplashScreenApi` is my main theme. And I change the application tag theme but not working. Show the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried using normal drawables instead of vector one?

Comment: Yes but same as before

Comment: What if I want to set the postSplashScreenTheme at runtime? For "installSplashScreen", it says I can use "setTheme", but it doesn't say when and where, and if I should remove installSplashScreen: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen.Companion#(android.app.Activity).installSplashScreen() "Alternatively, if a SplashScreen instance is not required, the theme can manually be set using Activity.setTheme."

Answer (score 0):

Update library version to **"androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta02"**. It works fine

Comment: It doesn't work.